# Is there a way to reduce the amount of lines in this code?

Tags: python

I made a code to filter a list of names based on certain conditions.. and wanted to see if I can reduce this further and eliminate redundancy in code. Here is my code:

```
names1 = ["Jane", "Jake", "Bradley", "Bill", "Betty", "Kara", "Kris", "Jil"]
names2 = ["George", "Kate", "Karen", "Kurt", "Greg", "Gary"]
selection_criteria = ["full_list", "four_characters", "three_characters",  "start_with_k", "start_with_z"]

def sublist (name_list, condition):
    return_list = []
    if condition == "full_list":
        return name_list
    if condition == "four_characters":
        for name in name_list:
            if len(name) == 4:
                return_list.append(name)
    if condition == "three_characters":
        for name in name_list:
            if len(name) == 3:
                return_list.append(name)
    if condition == "start_with_k":
        for name in name_list:
            if name[0] == 'K':
                return_list.append(name)
    if condition == "start_with_z":
        for name in name_list:
            if name[0] == 'Z':
                return_list.append(name)
    return return_list

for criteria in selection_criteria:
    print(sublist(names1, criteria))

for criteria in selection_criteria:
    print(sublist(names2, criteria))
```

Comment: If the code is working it's probably off-topic here. Try submitting to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: I condensed it down to one line for ya: https://i.fluffy.cc/lv6bGSsq8bVkFRzTwd7ZH0bS6KxP7qnH.html (via https://github.com/csvoss/onelinerizer)

Comment: Do what @Chris said. At first glance I see two `condition` types, `starts_with_*` and `*_characters`. You can extract the logic of those loops into functions which accept some `start_letter` and `name_length` respectively.

Comment: Why did you delete the code from the question? (Doing so changed this from an off-topic question to a meaningless question.)

Answer (score 0):

In Python, if you find yourself interpreting a string as the name of a function to perform, you'd probably be better off just passing the function itself.  Your `sublist()` function could be simply replaced by the built-in `filter()` function (or, on Python 3, perhaps `list(filter(...))` to get a list instead of a generator as the result).  Your list of possible criteria would become:

```
selection_criteria = [
    lambda n: True,  # or simply None instead of a lambda
    lambda n: len(n) == 4,
    lambda n: len(n) == 3,
    lambda n: n.startswith("K"),
    lambda n: n.startswith("Z")
]
```